# Отсутствует локализация по пустому поиску

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, поиск

Отсутствует перевод на страничке поиска при 0 результатов поиска

> [image: 0 результатов]

Comment: Спасибо. [Уже знаем](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41282350#41282350). Исправим, как лень поборем :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Переводы добавил. Должно появиться на сайте после подкачки Transifex и пересборки движка. Ожидается на сборке `> 2017.11.21.27823`.

Comment: Проверил, заработало :)

Comment: @nick_gabpe куда ему деваться :)